# Configure Wildfly to use resteasy from pom.xml, but not from Wildfly module

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

Wildfly 10 is configured with resteasy modules of 3.0.19.Final version.

Several applications are deployed and rely on this version. Wildfly configuration is not under my control, so I cannot request to add a new module with an updated version.

I want to force the war application, exclude default resteasy modules from deployment:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Add compile-time dependency into the pom.xml:

```
<resteasy.version>3.1.4.Final</resteasy.version>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
  <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
  <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, when application is deployed, the jax rs configuration class, is not triggered:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath(JAXRSConfiguration.APPLICATION_PATH)
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {
```

As soon as I get rid of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file, switch version to the default one, jax rs application is triggered and application handles requests.

How can I get it solved?

I have found an [JBoss Modules Suck, It’s Impossible To Use Custom Resteasy/JAX-RS Under JBoss 7](https://dzone.com/articles/jboss-modules-suck-it%E2%80%99s) article. Hope that it has been changed in new versions of WildFly